# Is A Relationships in ER Diagrams

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I'm working on an exercise to model and implemented a database for a university accommodation office.

Here is the ER diagram I have so far:

[image: ER Diagram]

The specification says that halls have a manger and apartments have the number of rooms. Otherwise the attributes are identical. Invoices and addresses need to have the address of the flat or hall.

Should I store the flat and hall entities in the same table? How else can I have one entity (place) linking two others?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the info tab for the following tags:  [single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance) [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key).

For simple cases, like yours, single-table-inheritance might be your best bet.  You will have a few NULLs in the attributes that don't apply to all rows, but that shouldn't be a major problem.

For complicated cases, class-table-inheritance works out better, but it's a little extra work.

Shared-primary-key is an extra technique you can use with class-table-inheritance to enforce the one-to-one nature of "is a" relationships.